# importing a type from `node_modules/@types` in vite

Tags: typescript, node-modules, vite

I am porting a TypeScript project I had created using Webpack to Vite. I have created a scaffolding with:

```
npm create vite@latest my-project -- --template react-ts
```

And started porting my code. In the original Webpack project I had the following in a file:

```
import GeometryType from 'ol/geom/GeometryType';
```

The definition of this type resided in:

```
node_modules/@types/ol/geom/GeometryType.d.ts
```

Vite is not able to find the file and complains with:

```
Failed to resolve import "ol/geom/GeometryType" from "src/components/gis/gis.tsx". Does the file exist?
```

How should I configure it to find the file under `node_modules/@types`?

My `vite.config.js` is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
    ]
  }
})
```

The `tsconfig.json` file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

I've tried various permutations of the below approaches, such as:

1. changing the import to read: `import GeometryType from '@types/ol/geom/GeometryType'`
2. adding `paths` and `baseUrl` properties to the `tsconfig.json` file
3. using the `vite-tsconfig-paths` package in my `vite.config.js`

None of the seemed to work.

The only solution that did work was doing the following two things: first, adding the following in the `resolve/alias` section of the `vite.config.js` file:

```
 { find: '@types', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules', import.meta.url)) }
```

**AND** then, also changing the import to be:

```
import GeometryType from '@types/ol/geom/GeometryType';
```

However, this seems like a hack.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Import symbols only from the root of the packages, do not dig into the structure of the package (except when the package documentation explicitly tells to do so). That should be `import GeometryType from 'ol';`. The symbols that are not exported by the package are private to that package. They can be renamed, changed, moved or even deleted without affecting the applications that depend on the package and import from it correctly.